# Running xcode 4.5 on iphone ios6 - Breakpoints are not working

Tags: debugging, ios6, xcode4.5

tried to run on simulator - worked. 
tried to run on ios 5.1 - worked.

Any idea?

Comment: Working fine for me. Try clearing derived data and doing a clean build.

Comment: Same problem here. Why it has been asked to close this question ???!! I simply open my project which works perfectly on previous versions of XCode (breakpoints work) but here, with 4.5, breakpoints are not taken into account only on device (ok on simulator). This is a VERY GOOD QUESTION ! Anybody managed to solve this issue ?

Comment: Here same problem. Please open the question.

Comment: The moderation is really going downhill on stackoverflow.

Comment: Same problem. Why are all the decent questions closed these days?

Comment: Yes, this would have helped me also